# Filtering rows based on date range

Tags: google-sheets, filter, filtering, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet where column A is the beginning date, and column B is the ending date.

I would like the sheet to only display rows if today's date is within this range (including beginning and closing date).

Any advice?  I'm working hard but it's outside my grasp right now.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=FILTER(A:C, TODAY()>=A:A, TODAY()<=B:B)
```